# How to set VPN killswitch of WLAN hotsport / tethering?

Tags: vpn, ip-address

I've been using [VPN Hotspot](https://github.com/Mygod/VPNHotspot) to share the VPN connection of a rooted Android device via WLAN hotspot. I have enabled permanent VPN connection and killswitch in the host device's system settings. However I couldn't find a killswitch option in the VPN Hotspot app. This poses a risk that when the VPN app failes to automatically reconnect after a disruption, my other devices connecting to its hotspot would expose to unprotected connection and survellience of the ISP. Is there a way to monitor VPN connection and turn off WLAN hotspot when VPN disconnection is detected, through an app, system setting, or Termux script?